# Is there a maximum to the output of PDO::debugDumpParams?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When using the PDO::debugDumpParams, is there a maximum number of characters the output will show for the "selected" query? After approx 500 characters the query is being ended in the middle of the query, while when outputting the prepare $query variable, the full query is being shown.

Also when removing certain parts of the query, it still show a part and not the full query (what I saw first, minus the part I remove, added a new piece which didn't show before).

Is this a know issue or is this something I can overwrite with the settings?

With kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Using the following script, I have been able to make `$pdoStmt->debugDumpParams()` write out more than 4000 characters. It seems the limit of 500 you are experiencing is not a hard limit of the function itself. Perhaps one of your operations to compose the query is limited to 500 characters?

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost', 'user', 'pass');

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT ' . implode(', ', array_fill(0, 500, "'test'")));

$stmt->debugDumpParams();
```

(This was on PHP 5.2.11.)