# PHP pdo query execution error

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I use php with pdo and `pdo_dblib` to execute long select query (in this case). If I run this query directly in sql I receive results but if I run it from php I receive

`207 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [207] (severity 16) [(null)]`

I use `debugDumpParams` to see what is the query after preparation but it dumps only the first 500 characters from the query and may be this is the problem. Is this some configuration parameter or this is a bug?

OS: Slackware
PHP: 5.4.7
pdo_dblib - compiled by myself
freetds - from http://slackbuilds.org/

[Is there a maxium to the output of PDO::debugDumpParams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016978/is-there-a-maxium-to-the-output-of-pdodebugdumpparams)

**EDIT:**

Code:

```
<?php
$dsn = 'dblib:host=XXXXXXXX;dbname=XXXXX';
$username='XXXXX';
$password='XXXXXXX';


$query = "select * from (
                select Row_Number() over (order by 
                order_status.id desc) as RowIndex,  
                order_status.id as ID,
                order_status.caller_type_id as CALLER_TYPE_ID,
                order_status.phone as PHONE,
                order_status.order_number as ORDER_NUMBER,
                order_status.caller_client_data_id as CLIENT_DATA_ID,
                order_status.caller_contact_phone_id as CALLER_CONTACT_PHONE_ID,
                order_status.record_date as DATE,
                order_status.call_date as CALL_DATE,
                order_status.call_time as jueCALL_TIME,
                order_status.username as USERNAME,
                client_data.ID as CALLER_ID,
                client_data.client_type_id as CLIENT_TYPE_ID,
                client_data.name as NAME,
                client_data.person as PERSON,
                client_data.country_id as COUNTRY_ID,
                client_data.city as CITY,
                client_data.street as STREET,
                client_data.street_number as STREET_NUMBER,
                client_data.living_complex as LIVING_COMPLEX,
                client_data.building as BUILDING,
                client_data.entrance as ENTRANCE,
                client_data.floor as FLOOR,
                client_data.apartment as APARTMENT,
                client_data.postal_code as POSTAL_CODE,
                client_data.description as DESCRIPTION,
                client_data.email as EMAIL,
                country.name as COUNTRY,
                client_type.type as CLIENT_TYPE,
                caller_type.name as CALLER_TYPE,
                contact_phone.phone as CALLER_CONTACT_PHONE
                from order_status order_status
                inner join client_data client_data on client_data.id = order_status.caller_client_data_id
                inner join client_type client_type on client_type.id = client_data.client_type_id
                inner join country country on country.id = client_data.country_id
                inner join caller_type caller_type on caller_type.id = order_status.caller_type_id
                inner join contact_phone on contact_phone.id = order_status.caller_contact_phone_id
             where 1=1 ) as Sub Where Sub.RowIndex >= ? and Sub.RowIndex < ?";


$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$prepare = $db->prepare($query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$bind = array(1, 11);
if (!$prepare->execute($bind)) {
    $prepare->debugDumpParams();
} else {
    echo "success";
}
```

Output:

```
SQL: [1841] select * from (
                select Row_Number() over (order by 
                order_status.id desc) as RowIndex,  
                order_status.id as ID,
                order_status.caller_type_id as CALLER_TYPE_ID,
                order_status.phone as PHONE,
                order_status.order_number as ORDER_NUMBER,
                order_status.caller_client_data_id as CLIENT_DATA_ID,
                order_status.caller_contact_phone_id as CALLER_CONTACT_PHONE_ID,
                order_status.record_date as DATE,
                order_status.call_date as CALL_DATE,
                order_status.call_time as jueCALL_T
Params:  2
Key: Position #0:
paramno=0
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #1:
paramno=1
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
```

Comment: are you using `var_dump` to output `debugDumpParams`?

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: Where to use var_dump? debugDumpParams outputs it directly ...

Comment: According to Google a 207 error occurs when SQL Server tries to use a column name that doesn't exist.

Comment: If I run this query in tsql I receive results, so the problem is not non existing column.

Comment: @BennyHill Problem is with column `call_time`. If I run this query `select call_time from order_status` I receive the same error from pdo.
If I change `call_time` to `id` there is no problem.

Comment: Just out of curiousity - what do you have your TDS_Version set to in your freetds.conf and odbc.ini files? Have you tried setting it to 8.0? I've seen this setting cause/fix several weird problems...

Comment: It was 7 but I set it to 8 and the problem sill remain :(.

Answer (score 0):

Set the TDSDUMP environment variable on the server for the PDO process.  The log will capture the missing messages and details you need.

Comment: In freetds.conf I remove comments from 

`dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
debug flags = 0x80`

and now I receive `Segmentation fault` when try to execute the php script.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for lost your time. I found my error - connect to 2 different databases in MSSQL.

P.S. `Segmentation fault` error still appear if I enable dump file in freetds configuration and I still does not know how to set `debugDumpParams` to output more than 500 characters [Is there a maxium to the output of PDO::debugDumpParams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016978/is-there-a-maxium-to-the-output-of-pdodebugdumpparams)